# Send input and get output using different threads to an exe file

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, pipe

I am trying to write a script that sends text and gets output from a given `.exe` file.
The `.exe` file sends to its output what the script will send to its input.
Send input and read output should be done using different threads.

```
import subprocess
proc=subprocess.Popen(['file.exe'],stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

stdout, stdin = proc.communicate()
proc.stdin.write(text)
proc.stdin.close()
result=proc.stdout.read()
print result
```

Now I can't find a way to communicate using separate threads.

Any guidance or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this. You send the input in the main thread and get the output in another.

```
class Exe(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self, text=""):
    self.text = text
    self.stdout = None
    self.stderr = None
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

def run(self):
    p = subprocess.Popen(['file.exe'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    self.stdout, self.stderr = p.communicate(self.text)

text = "input"
exe = Exe(text)
exe.start()
exe.join()
print exe.stdout
return 0
```